# change default segment for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I think my question is simular to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74724/set-a-default-segment-for-google-analytics, however it has not been answered since January and due to hight volume of spam lately, maybe google has added a feature i cant find.

I have 10 websites on a new overview showing sessions/bouncerate/time on site etc.. Looks very nice, however the numbers are not real as 40% is spam.
I then downloaded and edited a segment from the gallery and applied. When i enter one of the website and apply the segment it looks good.
BUT when i see the overview its still ALL SESSIONS showing and user HAS TO go in and change the Segment manually

Is there a way that I can remove ALL SESSION totally and replace it with my own "ALL Session -Spam"

I know i can use shortcut to make it easier for customers but that is only valid for that one link. If they click deeper in, the ALL SESSIONS are applied and data becomes unusable.

So remove ALL SESSION as default and apply my own "ALL SESSION -spam" as default.
Can this be done?
Thanks